# Counting the attempts of a random

Tags: java

I need to make a code that generates 20 random numbers with a range from 0 to 20, with the condition that if a random number is repeated with a previous one, count that repetition and change the number to one that has not been repeated.

I have this code:

```
int [] times = new int [21];
        int[] randoms = new int [21];
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            times[i] = 0;
            randoms[i]=(int)(Math.random()*21);
            //System.out.print(i);
            if(i>0){
                for (int j = 1; j < i+1; j++) {
                    while(randoms[i]==randoms[i-(j)] || randoms[i]==randoms[0]){

                        System.out.print(i+" , "+j+" "+(i-j)+" * "+randoms[i]);
                        System.out.println();
                        randoms[i] = (int)(Math.random()*21);

                        times[i]=1+times[i];
                    }
                }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, randoms[i]+" "+times[i]);
```

But, when i run the code There are some random numbers that repeat themselves, as if the "while" was not there.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: you solution is sub-optimal. instead create array of 20 ints 1-20 and Fisher-Yates shuffle it

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
randoms[i]=(int)(Math.random()*21);
```

Wont generate an number between `0 and 20`. Instead you should change it to something like this

```
randoms[i]=(int)((Math.random()*100)%21);
```

---

The other issue is if once you've found that number is repeating, then you replace it with another random number, **but** you never check whether that regenerated number is repeated or not, to check it, you can set the value of `j=0` again after regenerating  random number and go back to your `for` loop:

```
int [] times = new int [21];
int[] randoms = new int [21];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    times[i] = 0;
    randoms[i]=(int)((Math.random()*100)%21);
    //System.out.print(i);
    if(i>0){
        outerloop:
        for (int j = 1; j < i+1; j++) {
            while(randoms[i]==randoms[i-(j)] || randoms[i]==randoms[0]){

                System.out.print(i+" , "+j+" "+(i-j)+" * "+randoms[i]);
                System.out.println();
                randoms[i] = (int)((Math.random()*100)%21);

                times[i]=1+times[i];

                //recheck the entire loop again
                j=1;
                continue outerloop;
            }
        }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, randoms[i]+" "+times[i]);
```